# Is it possible to provide JavaScript with localization parameters

Tags: javascript, browser, localization

Well, I have a text field in my application which displays spell check in local browser languages. For example, it will show different spell check warnings to users in England and Denmark.

Probably, its a browser based property to pick up the locale. However, I want to know is it possible to override this behavior by specifying any locale or culture through JS code.

I tried searching for it, but didn't find any way out yet.

I would like not to disable the spell check. Any suggestions??

PS: If it matters I am working with Angular JS

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions：

- IP address
- navigator.language

For most use case,navigator.language is very useful.

Comment: Why would it be useful? Can you provide a working example how it would take place?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var type=navigator.appName
if (type=="Netscape"){
  var lang = navigator.language
}
else{
  var lang = navigator.userLanguage
}
var lang = lang.substr(0,2)

if (lang == "en"){
  console.log('en')
}

if (lang =='zh'){

  console.log('zh')
}
```

Comment: May be you can explain a bit of ur answer. Not very clear as to what is intended. How do I set the language for my app using this code

Comment: I'm sorry for that to you.In your application, you'd better to monitor to local navigator language in the initialize function .